# How to calculate aggregated values like TVL, total rewards disbursed etc. in an ethereum dapp

Tags: web3js, dapps

I need to showcase the total rewards disbursed for a user, or for the all the users in a dapp. To show this metric, I might have to manually get all the reward generation events and manually add them, which takes a while in my dapp or throws error when the number of events crosses 10k. How do we implement these aggregated value indicators?

Answer (score 3):

With web3.js, you're limited in terms of how many events you can fetch at once. You probably don't want to be making these calculations on the frontend, as they are very heavy and you would have to do them every time someone visits/refreshes your page. Load times and UX would not be pleasant.

For heavy calculations like these, which are based on an aggregation of tens och thousands of events, you probably should have a backend and a database where you calculate these values. Then you can save them to your DB, cache them and serve them to your frontend.

We have been trying ourselves to calculate TVL for Uniswap and Pancakeswap. It's an incredible amount of data that you have to go through. It's less if you're only looking for certain users TVL, but still, a lot of events to go through and filter to find what you're looking for.

In the end, the process we came up with was the following.

1. Find all token pairs by looking at all historical `PairCreated` events.
2. Read the reserves from token0 and token1 from the pair
3. Calculate the price of token0 and token1 in usd
4. Then calculate the reserves valued in USD

So you need access to an Ethereum node to get this data. And then a backend to process it probably. It depends a bit on the specific metric you're looking to calculate.

When me and my team realized the work that is required to get simple data like this, we started working on a solution. So in a few weeks, we should have a simple API where you can this the data you're looking for in one line of code, basically.

So full disclosure, I work at [moralis.io](https://moralis.io). So maybe check back in a few weeks, and this should be a lot easier.

Comment: hi @Filip would like to know which APIs are you using for TVL calculations

Comment: We don't use any API for this. We get all the data I mentioned above from the blockchain and we run the calculations ourselves. We offer the API so that everyone doesn't have to do the same thing we did.

Comment: we need that API for calculating TVL for our project, can you help me with that?